# Issue with getting substring in C

Tags: c, substring

I am new to C and working on a project where I need to be able to get a substring but I am having difficulty as there is a compiler warning about the initialisation and a core dump if I attempt to run the program which I am not sure how to resolve.

I have a function called `substring` which passes in the source string, the start index and to end index.

Below is my substring function.

```
char *substring(char * src, int from, int to)
{
    char * dst = "\0";
    strncpy(dst, src+from, to);
    return dst;
}
```

Below is how I am calling the function

```
char * debug = substring(rowReport[bPartyColIndex], 1, 2);
```

rowReport is a MYSQL_ROW, and bPartyColIndex is just an int equal 0 to reference the correct column from the MYSQL_ROW.

At the moment the line above has a compiler warning of:

```
 warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

which I am unable to determine how to fix this warning.

If I try and run the program I then get a coredump which says that it is a segmentation fault within the substring function performing the `strncpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char * dst = "\0";
strncpy(dst, src+from, to);
```

That's why there's a segfault. Assigning `dst` with `\0` isn't correct ! Actually, `dst` isn't big enough to store the `src + from` bytes. You should allocate it instead:

```
char *substring(char * src, int from, int to)
{
    size_t src_size = to + 1 - from;
    char * dst = malloc(src_size); // Assuming str + from is ok 
    if (dst != 0)
        strncpy(dst, src+from, src_size);
    return dst;
}
```

In this case, you will have to free `dst` :

```
char * debug = substring(rowReport[bPartyColIndex], 1, 2);
puts(debug);
free(debug);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate new memory for your substring, or have the caller pass in the desired buffer. What you're trying won't work, you are never allocating the storage.

You need something like:

```
char * substring(const char *str, int from, int to)
{
  const size_t len = to - from + 1;
  char *out = malloc(len + 1);
  if(out != NULL)
  {
    memcpy(out, str + from, len);
    out[len] = '\0';
  }
  return out;
}
```

Then the caller needs to `free()` the returned pointer when done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `substring` function, by itself, has some issues.  You are not allocating any space for `dst` and copying into it.  That could lead to a seg fault.  You are also not checking if either `from` or `to` my go beyond the end of string (can be checked with `strlen`).

You should also check that `from` is less than `to`.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
   char * dst = "\0";
   strncpy(dst, src+from, to);
```

You are writing to a string literal but string literals are immutable in C. This invokes undefined behavior.

Second:

`rowReport[bPartyColIndex]` has to be a `char *` but it is of a different type.

You didn't specify the type of `rowReport` in your question, but assuming it is a `char` array you have to pass `&rowReport[bPartyColIndex]` instead of `rowReport[bPartyColIndex]` to `substring` function.